# Durandal interfering with Knockout Bindings?

Tags: knockout.js, single-page-application, durandal

I have an application that I am building that is using Durandal and Knockout and there seems to be a problems when I use the durandal navigation to one of the pages in my SPA.  When I load the application from the home screen and navigate to my second page that has a series of cascading dropdowns it appears as though the bindings break.  If I refresh the page and load the second page to start with the bindings all seem to work as expected.  The first page has nothing on it other than a title right now, and the second page has the cascading dropdowns.  I am honestly not sure what code to include on this question so if there is anything people would like to see please feel free to ask.  I am peeking into the Knockout context using the 'Knockout Context' Chrome plugin and everything seems to be working except the results are not displayed.

The simplier view model that is having problems

```
define(['services/logger',
    "services/datacontext"],
function (logger, datacontext) {
    var manufacturers = ko.observableArray();
    var manufacturer = ko.observable();
    var isSaving = ko.observable(false);
    var modelsWithSizes = ko.observableArray();

    manufacturer.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        datacontext.getBikeModelsWithSizes(modelsWithSizes, newValue.manufacturerID());
    });


    var hasChanges = ko.computed(function () {
        return datacontext.hasChanges();
    });

    var cancel = function () {
        datacontext.cancelChanges();
    };

    var canSave = ko.computed(function () {
        return hasChanges() && !isSaving();
    });

    var save = function () {
        isSaving(true);
        return datacontext.saveChanges().fin(complete);

        function complete() {
            isSaving(false);
        }
    };

    var canDeactivate = function () {
        if (hasChanges()) {
            var title = 'Do you want to leave ?';
            var msg = 'Navigate away and cancel your changes?';
            var checkAnswer = function (selectedOption) {
                if (selectedOption === 'Yes') {
                    cancel();
                }
                return selectedOption;
            };
            return app.showMessage(title, msg, ['Yes', 'No'])
                .then(checkAnswer);

        }
        return true;
    };

    var vm = {
        activate: activate,
        cancel: cancel,
        canDeactivate: canDeactivate,
        canSave: canSave,
        hasChanges: hasChanges,
        manu: manufacturer,
        manufacturers: manufacturers,
        modelsWithSizes: modelsWithSizes,
        save: save
    };

    return vm;

    //#region Internal Methods
    function activate() {
        manufacturers(datacontext.lookups.manufacturers),
        logger.log('Frames View Activated', null, 'frames', false);
        return true;
    }


    //#endregion
});
```

The datacontext call is as follows

```
datacontext.lookups = {
    manufacturers: function ()
    { return getLocal('Manufacturers', 'name', true); }
};
```

Comment: You'll need to include some code like the 'Page' Viewmodels modules, and what calls your activate function

Comment: I've added the more simple of the viewmodels having problems. When you refer to the thing that calls the activate function are you talking about the shell.js with the router.map calls?

Comment: I'm curious if "datacontext.lookups.manufacturers" is an ajax or asynchronous call?   If so, that's tripped me as you are expected to return a promise from the activate call.

Comment: I added the datacontext call...it is a getLocal Breeze call which I believe should be synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

If datacontext.lookups.manufacturers is a preloaded observableArray, you probably need to change your activate function to:

```
function activate() {
    vm.manufacturers(datacontext.lookups.manufacturers());
    logger.log('Frames View Activated', null, 'frames', false);
    return true;
};
```

If datacontext.lookups.manufacturers is a async call to the web api, you will want to change it to:

```
function activate() {
    logger.log('Frames View Activated', null, 'frames', false);
    return datacontext.lookups.manufacturers().then(querySuccess);

    function querySuccess(data)
    {
        vm.manufacturers(data.results);
    };
};
```

Comment: It is a preloaded array, I have turned it into a function and included it in the original question.

Comment: I've experienced some issues when semicolons  were missing from my viewmodel file. Try to make sure all functions have an ending semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using breeze so I don't know if `getLocal()` is async or not, but if in doubt return a wrapped `$.when(syncOrAsync).then(...)`.

```
function activate() {
    var manufacturesPromise = datacontext.lookups.manufacturers();
    logger.log('Frames View Activated', null, 'frames', false);

    return $.when(manufacturesPromise).then(function(results){
       manufacturers(results);
    });
}
```

Comment: This makes a ton of sense.  But when I implement it my bindings are still broken and I have no idea why.

Comment: Would you be able to mockup the datacontext request and create a test case using OOTB Durandal? This repo (https://github.com/dFiddle/dFiddle-1.2) is work in progress and lacks in depth documentation, but it 's probably the fastest way to produce a test case that can be discussed here.

Comment: OOTB?  I can def start working on a fiddle that tries to reproduce the issue if you think that would help.

Comment: I have pushed up a repo @ http://pltaylor.github.io/dFiddle-1.2/ I have just started trying to mock the datacontext, and will continue to shim it until I can get it sorta running.

Comment: Rainer- I have mocked up the datacontext....and I am getting different errors than I was getting locally.  Would you like to take this conversation off of SO and on to email or some other method of conversation?

Comment: Taking at look right now. RainerATSpiritDOTde for offline conversation.